# Talk to Android Device via UDP via a wired connection (on Windows) - UDP port forwarding & port mirroring (like midimux)

Tags: usb, networking, windows

This is a continuation of an already asked question [Talk to Android Device via UDP via a wired connection](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/60722/44325) where the solution was "simple, using a shell cmd in the terminal".

> This was WAY simpler than I thought it was. I was trying to get this working for days now but it's actually really simple.
> My first approach was using reverse tethering, having the idea that I would need the Android device to get its Internet/LAN connection from the PC and not the other way around.
> Though that is not the case, just enable USB Tethering on your android device and thats all you need.
>
> After you did that, open a terminal emulator window on the device or open an adb shell session with the command `adb shell`. Enter `netcfg` to print out all the IPs and look for a device named `rndis0` or `usb0` or maybe another name, depending on your ROM or device. Simply look at all the devices that are "UP" and make sure its not Wifi or Mobile data connection, you can recognize them by the device name.
>
> If you think you found the correct adapter (it shouldn't show more than 2-3 devices that are listed as `UP` and have an valid IP next to it) simply send your OSC messages to that IP adress and it will work just fine. This should work with about any network protocol.

Terminal isn't on Play Store, so I guess that referred to configuring the device at the (Linux/Mac?) computer end.

My question pertains to Windows, re: [Mach's question @ hexler](https://hexler.net/forum/viewthread/1116).

[Failed attempt 1](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1zAnWDs34aO9QRbICYQUlklJlK7ZqiENc5d9SIsxr9v0/edit?usp=sharing)

OSC is an 'encoding', not a protocol (the co-author* tells us)

> OSC is an encoding not a protocol. Some OSC libraries and apps only support UDP for some reason but from the beginning it has been run over serial, TCP/IP and UDP. I have tunneled over MIDI too. oscuino shows you how to separate the encoding from the protocol.
>
> Because some applications only listen for OSC over UDP there is an advantage making the Teensy appear to be a source and sink of UDP packets.

So, it seems it can be done. Just haven't yet worked out *how*, on either Android or USB. I hope to ascertain how to configure USB tethering on Android, and port mirroring - I simply want clear instructions.

Additional links:

- https://imgur.com/G7GC2wX
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnesS.png
- https://forum.pjrc.com/threads/18849-Open-Sound-Control?p=27630&viewfull=1#post27630

Comment: There are terminal emulator apps like Termux ([F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/id/packages/com.termux/), [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux))